# Measuring IOPs and comparing with IOmeter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iops, iometer

So I've got to somehow generate IOPs using some prehistoric metrics used in IOmeter (which can't run in a 64bit ubuntu environment)

The settings used in `IOmeter` are:

```
16K block size, 
75% read to 25% write ratio, 
with 80% random distribution.
```

How would I replicate that using something like `fio` or `$other_tool`?

Answer (score 2):

fio comes with examples (in `/usr/share/doc/fio/examples` on my system). There is even one for IOmeter:

```
jed@test$ cat /usr/share/doc/fio/examples/iometer-file-access-server 
# This job file tries to mimic the Intel IOMeter File Server Access Pattern
[global]
description=Emulation of Intel IOmeter File Server Access Pattern

[iometer]
bssplit=512/10:1k/5:2k/5:4k/60:8k/2:16k/4:32k/4:64k/10
rw=randrw
rwmixread=80
direct=1
size=4g
ioengine=libaio
# IOMeter defines the server loads as the following:
# iodepth=1     Linear
# iodepth=4     Very Light
# iodepth=8     Light
# iodepth=64    Moderate
# iodepth=256   Heavy
iodepth=64
```

If you like the settings in there, you can probably just run

```
fio /usr/share/doc/fio/examples/iometer-file-access-server
```

If you want different settings, then copy the file, edit it, and enjoy.